# How to repeat each of the individual letters in a piece of text? in Java

Tags: java

As in a stutter the number of times specified by the provided multiplier if the text was "dean" and the multiplier 3, the result would be "dddeeeaaannn".

```
public static void repeatLetters()
{
   String text = "dean";
   int n = 3;
   StringBuilder repeat = new StringBuilder(text);

   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
      repeat.append("dean");
   }

   System.out.println(text);
}
```

Not getting the required result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What result are you getting? My guess is "dean" because you are printing out your orginal text not your built text. But your build text would return "deandeandeandean"

Comment: You are appending a whole word each time, not chars. Also, as mdewitt says, you are printing your original text, not your built one.

Comment: Youe outputting the word deans. Try iterating over the chars of the word and then each char print it 3 times. I would write answer but im on the cellphone. U need two 'forloops'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just appending the string itself n times for each character in it. You need to iterate through the string and append each character n times.

```
public static void repeatLetters()
{
    String text = "dean";
    int n = 3;
    StringBuilder repeat = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            repeat.append(text.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(repeat);
}
```

Also, another solution would be to use regular expressions.

```
public static void repeatLetters()
{
    String text = "dean", replace = "";
    int n = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) replace += "$1";
    System.out.println(text.replaceAll("(.)", replace));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Two problems:

1. You are not printing the String that you have manipulated, you are printing the original String you started with, ie `"dean"`. To print the string from the StringBuilder you can use

   System.out.println(repeat);
2. You are adding the whole word `"dean"` to your original word instead of adding individual letters/chars. You need to iterate through every letter in your original word and add those letters to an empty `StringBuilder`. Here is the basic logic you should use to get you going:

   - Get original word ("dean")
   - Create an **empty** `StringBuilder`
   - Parse through each letter of your original word ("dean") either by using a for loop and getting each char in the string or using String.split and parsing the Array.
   - For each letter in your original word, append that letter with that letter n times to your `StringBuilder`.
   - Print the string from `StringBuilder` once you have parsed through all the letters in the original word.

Comment: I am up-voting your answer because it is better than the one that I had posted. Good catch on also realizing that only the original text was being printed.

Answer (score 2):

You are simply appending the word "dean" to the end of your string three times.

Try instead looping through each char in the word dean and appending that char three times.

Something like this (this is pseudocode):

```
StringBuilder repeat = new StringBuilder();

ForEach( letter in "dean" )
    For( int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++ )
        repeat.add(letter);

Return repeat
```

Answer (score 0):

You are repeating the whole word here .. a possible fix is

```
public static void repeatLetters()
{
   String text = "dean";
   int n = 3;
   StringBuilder repeat = new  StringBuilder();

   for (int i = 0; i < text.length() ; i++)
   {
        for (int j= 0; j< n; j++)
            repeat.append(text.charAt(i));
   }

  System.out.println(repeat);
}
```

Comment: Should not create the builder with the original text in the constructor.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `charAt(i)`, not j?